# fluentd 運用時のエラー解消法を探しています。

Tags: centos, fluentd

fluentd 運用時のエラー解消法を探しています。

fluentdの設定ファイル `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf` の書き換えと `fluentd-cat` 実行、ログ確認を繰り返していると、fluentdが停止して `systemctl status td-agent.service` で確認すると以下のようなエラーが確認できます。

```
 td-agent.service - td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2021-09-07 05:31:08 UTC; 39min ago
     Docs: https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/td-agent
  Process: 3469 ExecStart=/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd --log $TD_AGENT_LOG_FILE --daemon /var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid $TD_AGENT_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 07 05:31:07 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Sep 07 05:31:07 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Trea...ata.Sep 07 05:31:07 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit td-agent.service entered failed state.
Sep 07 05:31:07 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service failed.
Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data.
Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for td-agent.service
Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Trea...ata.Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit td-agent.service entered failed state.
Sep 07 05:31:08 ip-172-31-44-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

こちらにエラー解消のため試したこと一覧を書きます。
これでも、根本解決できませんでした、心当たりあるかたお助けお願いします。

・td-agentの入れ直し
・td-agent関連ファイルの権限を777にする

Comment: 出た内容がそれです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

td-agent の設定ファイル `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf` の構文エラーを修正してから以下のコマンドを実行することで直りました。

```sh
systemctl restart td-agent
```